# Keyboard shortcut to switch focus without raising window

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, window-manager

So right now I have 'focus follows mouse' enabled, and windows don't automatically raise on focus, which means I can have a window in focus that is partially behind another window.

Now, when I use alt-tab to switch windows, it switches focus and raises the window, so that one will necessarily be on top.

Is there any way to switch windows in the same order as alt-tab, but only change the window with focus without raising the windows? I.e. I have a fullscreen window with another on top, I want to be able to switch between them with the keyboard and be able to type in either one, but still see both of these windows.

I'm using xfce, and running Debian. And I guess I'm using the default window manager, xfwm.

Thanks!

Comment: Erm. What window manager option? I would like to turn it into a keyboard shortcut though.

Comment: No, I'd like to keep both shortcuts, I want to be able to use `Alt`+`Tab` as it exists now and use a shortcut like this. And yep, I mean maximized window.